# Add current date and time, to a corresponding cell, when a cell value changes

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have Worksheet_Change code in my Excel worksheet. If there is a change in a given column it should add the date and time (from `Now()`) to a corresponding cell in a different column.

This sub should check two places and depending on which range was changed should update a different cell. If column G changes, update column A; if column K changes, update column M.

I'm not getting any errors. The date and time aren't being added to the corresponding cell.

It worked a few days ago.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As range)

Dim cell As range

'Adds unique keyA values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column G
If Not Intersect(Target, range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
        If cell.Value <> vbNullString And Target.Row > 7 And Target.Row <= 20 Then
        'Update the "KeyA" value
            sheets("Front End").range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
        End If
    Next cell
Else

'Adds unique keyB values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column K
    If Not Intersect(Target, range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value <> vbNullString And (Target.Row > "7" And Target.Row <= "27") Then
            'Update the "KeyM" value
                sheets("Front End").range("M" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

The code that changes the value in row G is called by a button:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Front End").Unprotect ("29745")
h = Hour(Now)
    For Each c In range("B8:B20")
        If h = Hour(c) Then
            c.Offset(0, 3) = CInt(c.Offset(0, 3)) + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c
Sheets("Front End").Protect ("29745")
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the function under the correct sheet, is it being called?

Comment: How is the data being changed? Manually, or by a formula recalculating?

Comment: the function is under the correct sheet, not being called. and the data is changing when the user hits a button in a userform

Comment: Is calculation mode set to xlCalculationManual?

Comment: Tested - your existing code works as I think you mean it to in my Excel 2013 install, whether in compatibility mode or in an xlsm, with Workbook Calculation set to Automatic.  What has changed on your computer since a few days ago?  Also, which version of Excel?

Comment: Does the button code turn events off?

Comment: @Yarnspinner what is calculation mode, ihavent messed with any settings like that.

Comment: @cxw im in excel 2013, and since then i made it so that instead of manually adding 1 to the value of the cell each time the user hits a button that opens a userform which prompts them to add or subtract 1 from the cell that goes with what hour of the day it is

Comment: You're not specifying which worksheet you want updated.  If the user is working from a form then the ActiveSheet may not be what you think it is; fully qualify your `Range`s and `Cells` etc with the name of the worksheet you want updated.

Comment: i added the name of the worksheet in front of the range with correct syntax and it still is not updating the cell in column A with Now()

Comment: How does the button code update column G?  Column B plus three columns (`Offset(0,3)`) is column E, right? --- Anyway, try removing the protection.  It may be preventing `Worksheet_Change` from changing the protected sheet.

Comment: when column E is changed, a calculation happens that changes column G

Comment: Calculations don't trigger the `Change` event.

Comment: @cxw i changed the column its checking for change to E and it worked! post that as an answer and ill mark it correct

Comment: You can try making sure Application.EnableEvents = True and Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range

'Adds unique keyA values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column G
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("G:G")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value <> vbNullString And Target.Row > 7 And Target.Row <= 20 Then
            'Update the "KeyA" value
                Range("A" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
            End If
        Next cell
    Else

'Adds unique keyB values
'Check to see if the changed cell is in column K
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("K:K")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value <> vbNullString And (Target.Row > "6" And Target.Row <= "27") Then
            'Update the "KeyM" value
                Range("M" & Target.Row).Value = Now()
            End If
        Next cell
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Worksheet_Change is not Selection_Change.

Comment: in what ways are they different, the user is not selecting a cell and changing it, a formula is changing the cell after a sub adds or subtracts 1 to the value of a different cell

Comment: that didnt fix it, i made the first line "selectionChange" and it still doesnt update the A or M columns when those values are changed

Comment: @Vbasic4now in your code you should also change the values in rows between row 7 and row 20. I have checked the code by me, it was working. Try with a little stop cells and see where you escape the if-s.

Answer (score 0):

Dont put it in a module, rather double click on the worksheet in the left hand pane when you launch developer. Module wont' work for private subs.